# Why is regionWillChangeAnimated: never called while panning?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator, mapkit

**The problem:**

My `MKMapViewDelegate`'s `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated` selector is never called while i pan the map (but is called while zooming) in iPhone 5.0 simulator. It works as it should (or at least i suppose it should) on 4.3 simulator and 4.3 device. I don't have access to 5.0 device at the moment.

**Situation:**

I have a MKMapView instance (created in Interface Builder) - i double checked it in viewWillLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    assert(self.myMapView);
    [self.stopMapView setDelegate:self];
}
```

I further define some of the `MKMapViewDelegate`'s selectors, but the ones that concern me are:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    RKLogDebug(@"Will Change map longSpan: %lf", mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta);
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    RKLogDebug(@"Did Change map longSpan: %lf", mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta);
}
```

What's going on here? The delegate is not somehow informed about the 'panning' in the MKMapView while on iPhone 5.0 Simulator. I already tried to reset simulator content but to no avail. I wonder whether is it just some simulator bug or iOS5's intended behavior? (I'm on 10.7.2 & Xcode 4.2).

Answer (score 1):

I added the two methods to my project. 
Tested iPhone 5.0 simulator: zooming / panning -> methods get called

I'm on 10.7.2 & Xcode 4.2 too.

So I can confirm it's not intented behavior as you thought it could be.

Hope it helps.